# How to find out the local IP Address of devices connected to a WiFi-LAN bridge

Tags: networking, ip, lan, bridge, wireless-bridge

In my home WiFi I have setup a raspberry pi to work as a WiFi-LAN bridge for my non-wifi devices... ('converts' the home WiFi to LAN)

I followed [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-bridge/amp/) tutorial

What do I have to do to find out the local IP addresses of my non-wifi devices in this subnet (only IPv4)?

Comment: Use the arp command.

Comment: You could run an IPscanner in that subnet

Answer (score 0):

What this WiFi-LAN "bridge" does is to register as a *single* device on your WLAN, and *masquerade* all the devices on the LAN connected to the RaspPi as this single device, as far as your WLAN is concerned.

So the "local IP addresses" in the WLAN subnet are the single address of the RaspPi.

The local IP addresses of the devices connected via LAN to the RaspPi is whatever `dnsmasq` has assigned them. You configured the `dhcp-range`. To see the concrete addresses, look at the leases `dnsmasq` has given out, usually in `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases`.

Let me repeat: These addresses are only valid inside the LAN connected to the RaspPi, you won't be able to reach those addresses from the WLAN.